# Slow query performance using GROUP BY, ORDER BY and LIMIT

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am having a problem with this query running on a table with 550k rows

```
SELECT "items".* FROM "items" 
WHERE (items.player_id = '1') 
GROUP BY items.id 
ORDER BY items.created_at DESC 
LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

The explain analyse indicates a serious problem with the ORDER BY part, which is taking 5.7 secs.

```
"Limit  (cost=64509.79..64509.91 rows=50 width=550) (actual time=5767.488..5767.499 rows=50 loops=1)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=64509.79..65867.39 rows=543041 width=550) (actual time=5767.486..5767.492 rows=50 loops=1)"
"        Sort Key: created_at"
"        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 50kB"
"        ->  Group  (cost=0.42..46470.36 rows=543041 width=550) (actual time=0.105..2668.933 rows=543024 loops=1)"
"              ->  Index Scan using items_pkey on items  (cost=0.42..45112.76 rows=543041 width=550) (actual time=0.099..989.441 rows=543024 loops=1)"
"                    Filter: (player_id = 1)"
"                    Rows Removed by Filter: 252"
"Total runtime: 5767.814 ms"
```

I have indexes on items.id, items.created_at, items.player_id, (items.id, items.created_at), (items.player_id, items.created_at), (items.id, items.player_id, items.created_at)

Comment: I would have an index based on your WHERE clause first, then group by, then order... (player_id, id, created_at)

Comment: Just be aware of what you're doing, which is sorting on a timestamp (or date, whichever) before retrieving 50 items.  This is going to essentially force an in-depth sort of the whole table on those unique properties before you can get those 50 items, regardless of the small limit on the query, and thus definitely needs optimization via an index.  Also, perhaps don't select .* and instead pick your columns individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you don't need to the GROUP BY clause, as this works only with aggregate functions, so remove that GROUP BY and the query performance will definitely get better.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need the `group by`?  The aggregation only works when `items.id` is unique -- which in turn means that the aggregation is not needed.

```
SELECT i.*
FROM items i
WHERE (i.player_id = '1') 
ORDER BY items.created_at DESC 
LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0;
```

You can then improve this query by adding an index on `items(player_id, created_at)`.